# Bluez not reading advertisement packet

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, raspberry-pi3, bluez

I'm trying to build a small program that reads the BLE beacons around my devices and parses the ones that I'm interested in to publish on MQTT. I'm using Raspberry Pis to run the code, I develop using my mac. The language is **JS** (Node 10.x), my Pis are running latest Buster, that is **Bluez 5.50** and a fork of Noble to interface with the bluetooth layer.

For some reason, on one of the Pis that I moved to an open area (in order to get clear readings), I only receive the Scan Response Packets. I never receive the Advertisement Packet. I do sometimes receive the Advertisement packet for one of the device that is quite far away, making me suspect that signal comes in play here. From the Pis in the network cabinet (small Faraday cage) I do get inconsistently both packets every now and then (reason for dedicating a Pi in an open location).

Is there any way to force Bluez to always receive the Advertisement packet? Is there a bug somehow or a feature that I am not using properly?

**EDIT**

I installed `tshark` to monitor closely, and I do see the advertisement packet reaching my device. This means that BlueZ is ignoring them. Is there some complete documentation on how to use `bluetoothctl` and how to configure the bluetooth deamon/tool in order for these packets to be read?

Answer (score 0):

After many days investigating, I manage to get the desired result for my project. I first thought of using the [bluewalker](https://gitlab.com/jtaimisto/bluewalker) project to access the raw packets. With this you can scan in *passive* mode, meaning only the advertising packet is retrieved.

By looking more in depth into [noble](https://github.com/noble/noble) project, the one I actually use to interface with, there is a workaround to scan in passive mode (https://github.com/noble/noble/issues/701), but also a variable to capture both advertising and response packets: `NOBLE_REPORT_ALL_HCI_EVENTS`. Setting this to **1** will give me exactly what I need, both the **scan request** which contains the data that changes more frequently, and the **scan response** that contains more data, such as min/max 24h values. And as a matter of fact, combining this setting with `duplicates=false` seems to give me only the **scan request** data, just like in passive mode.

**Question still opened:**

Having this, I still don't know how to use `bluetoothctl` to display both **scan request** data along with the **scan response**. Nor did I find a way to force the scan mode to *passive*. I could investigate more `hcitool hciconfig`, but they are deprecated (although every article on the internet refers to them).